# How to create circle shape UITableView in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios6

I want to develop following screen in IOS.

[image]

Question:-

Is there any other library that can help developing the desired screen?

How to develop such screen using custom view? I mean what are steps to develop such custom view easily?

Comment: image url : http://i.stack.imgur.com/DjFQs.jpg

Comment: is this kind of pie chart ?

Comment: please add code or demo you've tried otherwise this community isn't to help you here

Comment: its almost similar but not pie chart.

Comment: @PrashanthPatil is it static or dynamic ? just approve edit sugg so image can be visible to all ..

Comment: @vaibhav basically its static but when we clicked particular partition as some functionality....

Comment: go with the sanoj ans ..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can get the idea from this tutorial. You have to modify the code as well. Probably they are not using `tableView`.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit